# Ubuntu 17.10: How to display dock on-hover when mouse is on the left side of the screen?

Tags: gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock

i have installed ubuntu 17.10 and i am trying to get my dock to be displayed when hovering on the left side of the screen instead of making it fixed or displayed only when pressing the super btn (this is the current setting).

EDIT: for @pomsky

[image]

Comment: @pomsky i don't have the dock option there

Comment: yes i have another post with a different question with a screenshot: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1011321/ubuntu-17-10-desktop-customization-tweaks-not-in-sync-with-the-chrome-extensio @pomsky

Comment: themeing here is messy, thank you! still very confused